# window does not popup before process start -> tried sleep() method, but "fails"

Tags: c++, qt, sleep, qprocess

I tried to use the sleep method before some processes start just to give a popup window the time to appear:

```
    Processmethod()
{

    QDialog *ProcessMessage = new QDialog;      
    Ui::DialogProcessMessage Dialog;            
    Dialog.setupUi(ProcessMessage);             
    ProcessMessage->setModal(true);
    ProcessMessage->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose); 
    ProcessMessage->show();

    sleep(500);

    PROCESSES START                     
}
```

My problem is, that the popup window just appears after the process is finished instead of before the process starts. If I deactivate the process that should start after the window appeared the popup window works fine.Are the processes responsible for the popup window fail? Where is my fault? greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
qApp->processEvents();
```

before the sleep call.

Comment: hi could you tell me what `qApp->processEvents();` exactly means/does? - I read it in the qt doc, but I don't get it. I tried your proposal and the window also pops up before the process starts now, but the dialogs text is missing and it does not stay on top of my GUI although I set it `ProcessMessage->setModal(true);`.

Comment: qApp (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#qApp) is a global pointer to QApplication instance, it's provided by Qt. processEvents() (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) is a method which "flush" all events enqueued in the mainloop, including paintings and gui updates

Comment: ok, but it still does not work fine like I wrote in my first comment. Furthermore the processEvents() method prevents the GUI from freezing which was not my aim. The freezing is fine, just the popup window should pup up first.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `sleep` is Windows function? Do not use it. Use `QTimer` to start process later:

```
ProcessMessage->show();
QTimer::singleShot(500, processObject, SLOT(start()));
```

Comment: problem is that there are three processes called by three methods after the window popup. Isn't there anything more easy like sleep()?

Comment: @Streight, so, you have to make your own slot that starts processes. And what the difference, how may process you are going to start? I don't see how `Sleep` will help you actually. It just freezes the application, you needn't freeze, I belive

Comment: hmmm I am not sure. I thought the time between the `ProcessMessage->show();` and the processes start would be the problem the window could not pop up, that's why I tried to use sleep(). But now I think that maybe the following processes hinder the popup window to appear.

Comment: @Streight, unless you wait for process termination, process cannot hinder or freeze your application. You should understand that unless you has more than 1 thread, your program behavior will not change (in general), if you drop all _Sleep_ functions