# Why does the window not pop up?

Tags: c++, qt, popup, qprocess

I have the following source code:

```
    Processmethod()
{

    QDialog *ProcessMessage = new QDialog;      
    Ui::DialogProcessMessage Dialog;            
    Dialog.setupUi(ProcessMessage);             
    ProcessMessage->setModal(true);
    ProcessMessage->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose); 
    ProcessMessage->show();



    PROCESSES START                     
}
```

After I want to show the QDialog "ProcessMessage" there are three QProcess processes included in three different following methods. If I disable these methods with `//` the popup window appears just fine, but if I enable the methods, the processes run fine, but the popup window does not appear. Any ideas/solutions ? greetings

Comment: Seem that the error is in the Ui::DialogProcessMessage. Is it possible to have a look in there?

Comment: You call setModal(true) on the dialog, still call show().  Did you try using exec() instead of show()?

Comment: when I use exec() the window appears, but the processes don't start until I close the window. But my intention is to see the window with the processes running.

Comment: possible duplicate of [window does not popup before process start -> tried sleep() method, but "fails"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804081/window-does-not-popup-before-process-start-tried-sleep-method-but-fails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your window do not show until Process method is not return because main application loop implemented in main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        QDialog w; // or other window
        w.show();
        return a.exec(); // main app loop (all drawing procedures called from here
}
```

So if you call your PROCESSES START nothing happened until Process method returns in QApplication::exec()

You can start your processes in separate thread and send progress notification to you dialog by implementing signals\slots in queued mode

Comment: Isn't there any way to let the dialog pop up (staying on top of the main window) and just let it freeze with the main window?

Comment: Try to call static function QApplication::processEvents() before your long process start, in this case you see your dialog but appicatation will freeze until Processmetod() returns. If you do not want create separate thread you must time to time call QApplication::processEvents() in your long process after you change state of your dialog (update progress state, and then call QApplication::processEvents() to show it on display)

Comment: Ok, I tried that now and the window also appears, but the windows (dialogs) text is missing !?! Another idea: Isn't it possible to do a "do loop while method hasn't reached the end or while method hasn't returned an int" ? So I could just copy the Dialog into that loop - it's just an idea and I am not sure if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The dialog cannot be shown until your code execution exits `ProcessMethod()`. If you are using the `QProcess`es synchronously (by calling any of the `waitForXXX` methods), then this would cause the problem you are seeing. Anything else that holds up the main thread would also cause this problem.

Comment: Yeah I use `QProcess::waitForFinished(int)` in my processes